# Google map V3 user adding markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need some code that allows users to add their own markers to my map.  Does anybody have an example?

Thanks!

```
var initialLocation;
var siberia = new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105);
var newyork = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);
var browserSupportFlag =  new Boolean();

var stockholm = new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002);
var parliament = new google.maps.LatLng(59.327383, 18.06747);
var marker;
var map;


function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);



  // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  // Try Google Gears Geolocation
  } else if (google.gears) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
    geo.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeoLocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
  } else {
    browserSupportFlag = false;
    handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
  }

  function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag == true) {
      alert("Geolocation service failed.");
      initialLocation = newyork;
    } else {
      alert("Your browser doesn't support geolocation. We've placed you in Siberia.");
      initialLocation = siberia;
    }
  }
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  placeMarker(event.latLng);
});

function placeMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location, 
      map: map
  });


  map.setCenter(location);


  $.ajax({
     url: 'myPHP',
     data: location,
     succes: function(){
       alert('marker was added');
     },
     error: function(){
       alert('marker wasn't added');
       marker.setMap(null);
     }
  });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not a hard job:

- Set a click event on the map

  ```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
  ```
- Place the marker and make an AJAX call to the server to save the location in the database:

  ```
  function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location, 
        map: map
    });


    map.setCenter(location);


    $.ajax({
       url: 'myPHP',
       data: location,
       succes: function(){
         alert('marker was added');
       },
       error: function(){
         alert('marker wasn't added');
         marker.setMap(null);
       }
    });
  }
  ```

Comment: Hmm...  It does seem like that should work, but for some reason it's not.  I have updated with the code I am using.  Can you see what's wrong?

Comment: @user547794 - the addListener should be placed inside the initialize method, and you are aware that the $.ajax method in Harmen's code is only an example and it won't work just by placing it in your code, right?

Comment: It's just an example to give you an idea, but if you don't have much experience with Javascript, jQuery and Google Maps this might not help you.

Answer (score 1):

Or, use [MarkerManager for maps API v3](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/examples.html) and rid yourself of any kind of other little mistake you could make implementing this (like moving markers etc)